# How to set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` from powershell?

Tags: ubuntu, powershell, environment-variables

## Scenario

While implementing an unattended installation of some software on WSL Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows Powershell, the `apt upgrade` comand returns the following prompt:

[image]

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146283/how-to-prevent-prompt-that-ask-to-restart-services-when-installing-libpq-dev) nicely explains that one can prevent this prompt by setting the environment variable in WSL Ubuntu 18.04 before running the `apt upgrade` command. I verified this indeed works. However I am experiencing some issues setting that environment variable for WSL Ubuntu 18.04 from Powershell. These issues are elaborated on in section "Attempts".

## Question

How can I set the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` in WSL Ubuntu 18.04 from a powershell script?

## MWE

An MWE with some attempts is included below.

```
# First define path to the installed ubuntu1804.exe
$str1="/Users/"
$str2="/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/ubuntu1804"
$hdd_name=(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).SystemDrive
$username=$env:UserName
[String] $ubuntu1804_path=$hdd_name+$str1+$username+$str2


Write-Host "Done with setup now starting apt update ."

# perfrom apt update
$str1=" run 'yes | apt update'"
$command=$ubuntu1804_path+$str1
invoke-expression -Command $command

Write-Host "Performed Update, now setting env variable."

# set environment variable DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
$str1=" run DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive"
$command=$ubuntu1804_path+$str1
invoke-expression -Command $command 

Write-Host "Performed setting env variable, now performing upgrade."

# perfrom apt upgrade
$str1=" run 'yes | apt upgrade'"
$command=$ubuntu1804_path+$str1
invoke-expression -Command $command

Write-Host "Performed upgrade."
```

## Attempts

Initially I tried to set the environment variable by parsing `bash -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` from WSL. Next I tried `wsl DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`. Then I tried the `invoke-expression -Command` as described in the MWE. All of these either hang on the prompt (the first 2 don't show the prompt but keep waiting indefinitely, (I waited 2hrs+ each, and verified the command in wsl itself takes only +- 30 mins)), the latter goes to the prompt in powershell:
[image].

## Doubts

I think the observations from the 3 attempts imply either of 2 cases:

1. I am not setting the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` correctly from powershell.
2. Or, the powershell sets the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` correctly in some shell, but then opens a new shell for the next command, in which the environment variable is not set.

To verify I set the environment variable correct, I tried running `wsl printenv`, however this returns a different list then when I run the `printenv` from wls. If I manually set the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` in wsl, the `printenv` command correctly displays the environment variable. However, if I close and re-open the WSL Ubuntu 18.04 and re-run the `printenv` command, the environment variable has disappeard. This observation implies option 2 of the doubts is possible. I have not yet found a way to determine whether the environment variable is set correclty from powershell, as it is not among the output of `printenv` in powershell, when it is in the WSL output of `printenv`.

Comment: [1] why on EARTH are you using `Invoke-Expression` to run powershell commands? it seems unneeded ... and is known to be risky. think "SQL injection". [2] you have so much extraneous code posted that i cannot find where you are trying to set any environment variable. PLEASE, do as recommended and post a _minimal_ code example of the _specific problem_. [3] the usual way to set an EnvVar for the entire system is to use `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('VarName', 'VarValue', 'machine')`.

Comment: [1] My parser is a method inside a class which I considered not minimal enough, I currently do not yet have the knowledge to implement the `Write-Host wsl` nor `bash -c` commands without throwing errors in the more elaborate MWE I had. [2] Thank you, I assumed people would prefer being able to just run the code from copy paste, instead of having to first manually install the WSL etc, but I think this obfuscates the code too much for others, I adapted it to less code at the cost of more manual work. [3] Thank you, I will test if this environment variable also propagates to the WSL.

Comment: thank you for the added info. i don't understand your reasoning for [1], but that is _my_ problem. i would still avoid using `Invoke-Expression` unless there is no other way. right now, it looks like your commands would work as just bare commands OR via `Start-Process` - and both of those are more robust and safer. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

After searching git for powershell scripts that contained `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` I found [an example](https://github.com/jetersen/setup/blob/05d8c9af0672447bf8114b88cce0933f61b82481/scripts/WSL.ps1) that shows one can specify an environment variable for a specific command, from a powershell script, with the following command:

```
# First define path to the installed ubuntu1804.exe
$str1="/Users/"
$str2="/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/ubuntu1804"
$hdd_name=(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).SystemDrive
$username=$env:UserName
[String] $ubuntu1804_path=$hdd_name+$str1+$username+$str2

# Run a command with an environment variable
$str1=" run DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade -y"
$command=$ubuntu1804_path+$str1
invoke-expression -Command $command
```

I verified this indeed prevents the prompt for any user interaction, which solves the XY-problem. Even though I am not yet able to verify this directly by inspecting the environment variables of that shell, I **assume** this indeed (temporarily) sets the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`.